# Puppet existing directory to bool

Tags: puppet

is it possible to use a function, which checks if the given directory/file exists and assigns the boolean return value to a variable?

I want to execute a part of my manifest only if a file/directory doesn't exist.

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a [custom fact](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.1/custom_facts.html) to get that piece of information from the agent to your master. The easiest way to do this is an [external fact](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/facter/2.1/custom_facts.html#external-facts). On Linux, this scriptlet would suffice.

```
#!/bin/sh

[ -d /the/directory/in/question ] || exit 0

echo 'my_directory=present'
```

You can then use the `$my_directory` fact in your manifests. It's missing if the directory is not yet there, and otherwise has the value `'present'`.